# Music won't play through headsets

Tags: lumia-520, xbox-music, headset

My Nokia Lumia 520 accepts headphone but won't play sounds through them even in max volume. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your headphone jack?  I've had to do it before on one of the Windows phones.  I don't know availability.  Good thing is that the 520, with it's removable jack, is easy to work on.